# How do I get Messages on OS X to text to a phone number?

Tags: macos, ios, messages, sms

I recently rebooted an OS X machine on which I had an ongoing conversation in Messages via text with a phone number on a non-iOS phone. Now, though I am able to continue sending texts from Messages on iOS to exactly the same number, I can no longer send texts to that number from Messages on OS X, instead messages fail to send, the two conversations are no longer synced between OS X and iOS, and I'm told that the "phone number is not registered with iMessage".

How do I get OS X Messages to remember that I can, in fact, text that number?

Comment: I would try the steps noted here: http://www.macrumors.com/2014/11/06/text-messages-phone-calls-on-your-mac/ Go through and turn text message forwarding off then on again for that device, and then proceed from there. A few good troubleshooting tips at the bottom of the page, too.

Comment: in your phone, under settings -> messages -> text message forwarding is your mac listed and active?

Comment: @Matte.Car: Incredibly (typically? frustratingly? Apple-ly?) no. The reboot of my Mac apparently disabled this setting on my iPhone. Hurray for security!

Comment: Strange, it never disabled for me...

Comment: @Matte.Car: Weird stuff like this happens more and more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check "Text Message forwarding" under phone *Settings > Messages > Text*. This must be on (and your iOS device and OS X machine must be on the same network) for text messaging from Messages on OS X to work.

(It's possible this was disabled disabled for his Mac after a reboot.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure for txt, but if that happens for iMessage, then reselecting the 'correct' number from the To: *someone* header above the text area [even if it looked right to you in the first place] can make it have a rethink.

The area would show as red before, blue or green after 'fixing'. If 'no fix' is required then there is no colouration to that part until clicked on.

<sup>I don't have a red example right now…</sup>

[image]

Also, make sure their number in your Contacts is not listed as iPhone - mobile or cell should be OK.

Comment: Yes, that's what occurred to be to try first. But it doesn't work. It thinks things are fine for a second (or claims to think it does) and then fails again as before.

Comment: I had one number on my phone last year that went like that - but this was before SMS from Mac capability, so I'm not sure what's changed in how the Mac 'thinks' of the contact info, sorry.  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148579/mark-phone-number-as-cannot-receive-imessages but there was no resolution [it was 'fixed' when they actually bought an iPhone]

Answer (score -2):

On your computer, use AIM (AOL instant messaging, aim.com  .  it synchs with Imessages (just add the account), and it is happy with phone numbers. Enter the phone number there.